# Get Records from Salesforce using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, salesforce, odata, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use Azure Logic Apps to read data from one of the Salesforce objects which has huge number of records.  The Salesforce connector fetches the record and returns the pagination link as @odata.nextLink. But when I try to use a JSON parser to read the value it’s coming as null.

I tried to access the nextlink in a browser but it requires authentication. What authentication do we pass here ?

I would like to use an until action to iterate till I get a next link . So how do I check the condition for the until loop ?

Answer (score 1):

`nextLink` doesn't look like core Salesforce thing, it might be the OData connector preprocessing the results for you. You'd have to consult the documentation for the connector (if any).

Salesforce's REST API will return field with `nextRecordsUrl` if there's next page of results, you'd call that in loop until the field disappears. You'd call it like any other REST API resource available after login, by passing `Authorization: Bearer <sessionId also known as accessToken here>`. Again - probably the connector abstracts this away from you. Don't think you can send headers like that in browser, you'd need curl, Postman, SoapUI or similar http client.

If you don't get better answer and documentation is scarce - consider using raw REST API. Or Azure Data Factory has an almost-decent Salesforce connector?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm

Comment: Yes ADF connector is better for bulk exports